# Convert mysqli query result to 2 dimentional arrays

Tags: php

I want to run a single query and get all rows into individual 2-d arrays.
How can I acheive that? Thanks

table data:

```
|id|name (unique)|value1|value2|value3|
| 1|car          |small |medium|large |
| 2|fruit        |apple |orange|peach |
| 3|animal       |bird  |cat   |dog   |

$query = "SELECT * from table";
```

Expecting result:

```
$item['car'] = array('value1' => 'small', 'value2' => 'medium', 'value3' => 'large');
$item['fruit'] = array('value1' => 'apple', 'value2' => 'orange', 'value3' => 'peach');
$item['animal'] = array('value1' => 'bird', 'value2' => 'cat', 'value3' => 'dog');

echo $item['car']['value1']; // example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `$mysqli` object, prepare and execute your statement

```
$preparedStatement = $mysqli->prepare(query);
$preparedStatement->execute();
$results = $preparedStatement->get_result();
$item = array();
```

Then iterate through the returned rows and populate your `$item` array

```
while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = $row['name']; unset($row['name']); unset($row['id']);
    $item[$name] = $row;
}
```

Then,

```
echo $item['car']['value1'];
```

should give you `small`.

Comment: Straight and simple. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

get all data then group it to 2d array , like:

```
 $groups = array();
foreach ($DBresults as $rs) {
  $key = $rs['name'];
  if (!isset($groups[$key])){
    $groups[$key] = array();
  }
   unset($re['name']); // maybe useless
   $groups[$key][] = $rs;
}
```